# Where is the Jenkins working directory located?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Situation:
I installed Jenkins on my vserver and setup a "freestyle pipeline". I connected it via webhook push to my github which works (when I push to the repository, a new build job is started in jenkins).

Problem:
I can't seem to find the working directory where the git pull is executed in. I already searched for answers and many people say $JENKINS_HOME, but `echo $JENKINS_HOME`returns a blank line for me. Did I do anything wrong or where is my project then? Also, can I set the path to where the repository is pulled to a custom path (say /root/myprojectname)?

EDIT:
I can see the workspace in Jenkins webuserinterface but I can't find the corresponding folder on the vservers drive.

Comment: Did you try: echo "${JENKINS_HOME}"?

Comment: @mkemmerz it still prints an empty line.

Comment: Ok then try toexecute a pwd / dir command. This should always work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you check in /var/lib/jenkins. By default the jenkins home directory lies there as well in case of linux servers. It should also show you the home directory by browsing Manage Jenkins--> Configure System

Comment: Thank you, I think I found the current build in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` path :D